# How to ensure a unique number field with zero order

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Here is a table that has fields id, id_user, order_id.
Required when creating a record to find the last number of user and insert the following in order.
I wrote a stored procedure that takes the next order number to the user, but even it does not provide a unique order number.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_next_order()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  next_order_num bigint;
BEGIN
  select order_id + 1 INTO next_order_num
    from payment_out
   where payment_out.id_usr = NEW.id_usr
     and payment_out.order_id is not null
order by payment_out.order_id desc
   limit 1;

--  if payments does't exist, return 1
  NEW.order_id = coalesce(next_order_num, 1);
  return NEW;
END;
$function$

CREATE TRIGGER get_next_order 
 BEFORE INSERT 
     ON payment_out 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE 
PROCEDURE get_next_order()
```

How can I avoid duplicate order numbers?

Comment: You can create a custom `sequence` for that http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html -- or (more simply) just define that field to be `serial` (only works with `create table`, will not work with `alter table`)

Comment: I've never done composite "sequence". If there is an example I will be grateful to you.

Comment: That won't be *composite*. Any table can *own* any number of sequences (actually they don't *need* to own that sequence either: a `default` expression on that column can be enough). The only thing that you should be aware of, that these sequences could have *holes*, but if you use that column only for ordering, that won't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work in the presence of multiple concurrent transactions inserting orders for the same user, you need a lock on a particular record to make them wait and execute serially.

e.g., before the first SELECT, you might:

```
PERFORM 1 FROM "users" where id_user = NEW.id_user FOR UPDATE;
```

where you lock the parent "users" record that owns the orders.

Otherwise, multiple concurrent transactions could execute your procedure at the same time, but they can't see each others' inserted values, so they'll pick the same numbers.

However, beware: A foreign key constraint will cause a `SHARE` lock to be taken on the `users` entry already, when you insert into a table that depends on it. Your trigger will try to upgrade that into an `UPDATE` lock, but multiple transactions might already hold the `SHARE` lock, so this will block. You'll land up with transactions all waiting for each other, until PostgreSQL kills all but one of them in a deadlock abort error. The only way to avoid this is for the *application* to `SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id_user = blahblah FOR UPDATE` *before* it creates the orders for that user.

A variant is to keep a `next_order_id` field in `users` and do an `UPDATE users SET next_order_id = next_order_id + 1 RETURNING next_order_id`, and use the result of that to set the order ID. The same lock upgrade problem applies.